# При запуске Electron ошибка

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: electron-v6.0-win32-x64-unknown 
Found: [node-v57-win32-x64-unknown, node-v72-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module <br>'C:\Home\work\kvzrm\terminal\app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v6.0-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
Require stack:
 C:\Home\work\kvzrm\terminal\app\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js
```

Запуская електрон вижу это, в консоли, как поправить?

```
npm rebuild
```

не момог

Comment: `This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system` - пробовали?

Comment: @T0xee.n17 Конечно, первым делом.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/565